# Changing view repositions them at (0,0)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview

I created a simple window with the purpose of being something like a "Wizard" (I know Apple guidelines basically forbid you to, I tried to convince the customer, but whatever.

It is just a simple view with two Custom Views inside, one in the bottom part which contains a "previous" and "next" button, and a bigger view at the top which takes most of the space.

I called the bottom view "NavigationView" and the top one "ContainerView".

I created an array to hold a series of views the user is supposed to navigate through with the "next" and "previous" buttons.

So, here's my code.

```
- (IBAction) next:(id)sender{
    currentViewIndex++;
    [self animatePushView:YES];
}

- (IBAction)previous:(id)sender{
    currentViewIndex--;
    [self animatePushView:NO];
}

- (void) animatePushView:(BOOL)forward{
    NSView *nextView = [viewCollection objectAtIndex:currentViewIndex];

    for (NSView *subView in [containerView subviews]) {
        [subView removeFromSuperview];
    }

    [containerView addSubview:nextView];
    [nextView setFrame:containerView.bounds];

    [containerView setNeedsDisplay:YES];

}
```

It's pretty straightforward I think. I have an array which contains the next view to be displayed.

What happens is that I find the next view centered in the lower left part of the ContainerView. Why does this happen?

Also, as you may have guessed, I'm a newbie at managing views, even though I've been working on objective-c for quite some time, so if there's some best practice I'm missing I'm open to suggestions.
Thanks!

EDIT:

I forgot to add:
Some of these views have different sizes, and I would like to be able to change the window size according to the view size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.. Finally..

The problem was that the first view I had to show was already contained in the container view in the .xib file.

I don't really know why, but it probably caused some problem with the retain count of the container view, because it was released on the first click.
Releasing the container view would reposition the view on (0,0) probably because its frame was null, and the view would flash because it wasn't retained correctly.

Removing the view from the .xib file and adding it via code works properly anyway.

Answer (score 1):

`[nextView setFrame:containerView.bounds];`

You are assigning container view *bounds* to the next view *frame* ([doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Transforms/Transforms.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003290-CH204-BCIDJJBI)).
What you probably want is assigning the current view *frame* to the next view *frame*, and possibly adjust width and height.

Keep a reference to the current displayed view, something like this (_currentView is an ivar of type `NSView *`) :

```
- (IBAction) next:(id)sender{
    currentViewIndex++;
    [self animatePushView:YES];
}

- (IBAction)previous:(id)sender{
    currentViewIndex--;
    [self animatePushView:NO];
}

- (void) animatePushView:(BOOL)forward{
    NSView *nextView = [viewCollection objectAtIndex:currentViewIndex];
    [nextView setFrame:_currentView.frame];

    [_currentView removeFromSuperview];    // _currentView is retained in the collection
    [containerView addSubview:nextView];
    _currentView = nextView;

    [containerView setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}
```

Comment: I tried your code, and just like mine did, it just flashes the view in the bottom left corner of the window. After that flash the view disappears.
I guess there must be some other problem with my code.
Maybe the views aren't correctly retained?

Edit:
I declared the views as retained properties. That's the only change I did, and now the views are 'flashing' just like before, but at least they flash in their correct position..

Comment: Not sure if the positioning issue is due to the views not being retained correctly, views are stored into the collection. View frame is expressed in the parent coordinate system, once you get one view correctly positioned into the container view, it's easy the set the same frame on the next view. But we had only a small part of the whole code. The flashing problem also doesn't sound good, are deallocating your views after each switch ?

Comment: Nope, not at all.
That's actually the whole code that uses those views, I don't reference them in any other part of my code.
I added another answer that I found out, maybe it has something to do with the retain count?